# Adobe Analytics - Different domain for s_vi cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, adobe, adobe-analytics

I'm working on a ecommerce site which uses both Data Insertion Api and javascript (AppMeasurment.js) to send data to Adobe collecting servers. I need to read the s_vi cookie value in order to send data from backend.

When I look a the requests in firefox, the s_vi cookie has a different domain than my domain (I'm testing on localhost), so I can't read it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The s_vi cookie is set in a response from your Data Collection Server (e.g. 'metrics.yoursite.com'), so you can only see that cookie in a matching domain space (e.g. 'yoursite.com'.)

To test on localhost, you could try using Fiddler to map requests for 'yoursite.com' to your localhost (or machine name) so your browser will send the cookie with those requests.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Nils. I would like to test this on multiple environments (dev, qa, production).  Is there any other solution than generating my own Visitor Id ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Adobe Analytics is implemented with 3rd party cookies, but because of the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), javascript can only read cookies that are set on the same domain as the page.

If you already have your own system in place for tracking visitors by an id, you can explicitly set `s.visitorID` and it will override the default id. If you go this route, then you don't need to read the cookie, as you already have the value exposed.

Alternatively, you can implement the [Visitor ID Service](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/mcvid/mcvid_implement.html) which is a cross-domain 1st party cookie solution (*Note: I have found that it does not work 100% cross-domain though, depending on how strict a visitor's browser settings are, particularly in IE*). Because this is a first party cookie solution, you will then be able to read the cookie with javascript.